# Converting Python time.asctime() to Swift Date using DateFormatter

Tags: ios, swift, unicode, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

I am working with a series of string representations of timestamps returned by [time.asctime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) in Python. The documentation states:

> Convert a tuple or struct_time representing a time as returned by gmtime() or localtime() to a string of the following form: 'Sun Jun 20 23:21:05 1993'. The day field is two characters long and is space padded if the day is a single digit, e.g.: 'Wed Jun  9 04:26:40 1993'.

I've referenced [Unicode Technical Standards](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) to determine how I can instruct an instance of Swift's `DateFormatter` how to interpret the string and create a `Date`.

The UTS is very clear, but my `Date` object still unwraps to `nil`:

```
let dateAsString = measurement[2]
print("Date as string: \(dateAsString)")
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss y"  
let date = df.date(from: dateAsString)
print("Date: \(String(describing: date))")
```

Output:

```
Date as string: Thu Oct 20 17:53:06 2022
Date: nil
Date as string: Thu Oct 20 17:53:06 2022
Date: nil
Date as string: Thu Oct 20 17:53:16 2022
Date: nil
```

Comment: I always have to hunt down the docs on format strings and look this stuff up. One trick: After configuring your DateFormatter, pass a Date into its `string(from:Date)` function and log the output. That usually helps you figure out what’s wrong with your format string.

Comment: This is the link I used for DateFormatter format strings: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: I did the same and got this output `Date as string: Thu Oct 20 17:53:06 2022
Optional(Date: 2022-10-20 12:53:06 +0000)`

Comment: When I run this in a playground and substitute `Thu Oct 20 17:53:06 2022` for `measurement[2]` I confirm I also see your output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When printing `dateAsString` to console output, I did not notice that there is a single trailing whitespace after the year. Adjusting the Unicode format string to the following solved the problem:

```
df.dateFormat = "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss y " // <- observe the extra space
```